# When I update Xcode 11 beta3 version I can't find dark mode switch on Simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-darkmode

anybody know where the switch that can open dark mode is ?
Xcode beta2 ,simulator, in setting->developer->dark mode switch
but Xcode beta3, I can't find that switch

Comment: For me, it's still in the same place in Beta 3.

Comment: I have find it locate near by the debug tool!!!